# Laravel 5.1 Clean way to pass parameter in $request->all()

Tags: parameters, request, laravel-5.1

I am looking for a way to insert post_id value into $request->all(). The code I have so far is:

```
        public function createReview(ReviewRequest $request, $id) {

        $review = Auth::user()->reviews()->create($request->all());
        $review->task_id = $id;
        $review->save();

        return $review;
        }
```

Even though its working, I'm looking for cleaner way to do it. My models are:

```
User: hasMany->reviews ; hasMany->task
Review: belongsTo->user ; belongsTo->task
Task: belongsTo->user ; hasMany->reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

Well one way would be using a hidden input field like:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{$task->id}}">
```

or if you use the **Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider** and **Blade**:

```
    {!! Form::hidden('task_id', $task->id) !!}
```

Then your createReview method would look a lot cleaner:

```
    // Controller

    public function createReview(ReviewRequest $request) {
    $review = Auth::user()->reviews()->create($request->all());

    return $review;
    }
```

Don't forget to adjust your routes.php. You can also add

```
    // ReviewRequest.php

    $rules = [ ...,
    'task_id' => 'required',
    ];
```

to your rules in ReviewRequest to make sure that every review belongs to a task when you create it.